# IPHONE: Can I use GPS without internet to get current LATITUDE AND LONGITUDE

Tags: ios4, gps, iphone-3gs

I am creating an application in that I need only current Latitude and longitude of the device using the GPS i.e. using iPhone4.

I just want to know Do I need the Wifi or internet connectivity or not ??

I do have operator card as well as my device will be jailbroken and also having 3g facility means iphone 3gs or iPhone 4.

So can I get Lat and Long for the same ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data connectivity is only used by A-GPS ([Assisted GPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_GPS)) to find and use satellites faster and better in conditions where there are poor radio signals. Standalone GPS, per se, does not require any data connectivity to perform its function. However, if you start your application or the iPhone in an area where signals are low or poor, and you don't have data connectivity, your device (and the GPS on-board) will not likely be able to connect to satellites to get location information.

Comment: Hey ayaz , can you let me know If the GPS is turned OFF then is it possible to get current location ? means if user has OFF the location option from settings of iPhone then Can I use the GPS to get the current location or any way to get Lat and Long ?

Comment: If you haven't GPS enabled and even haven't internet data connection, then it could be possible with location based on cell tower, but of course your device should have cellular chip installed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use GPS for it as it doesn't need internet connection, but it

(1) takes a long time to get position and
(2) doesn't work properly inside buildings or streets

By this way you can do it:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{

    CLLocation * currentLocation = [locations lastObject];

    NSLog(@"%f",currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    NSLog(@"%f",currentLocation.coordinate.latitude);

    if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0) {
        return;
    }
    NSTimeInterval interval = [newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if (abs(interval)>20) {
        return;
    }
}
```